# Can a junior "appreciate" a senior's work

Tags: word-usage

Is it OK for a junior( a student or an official) to say "I really **appreciate** your work" to his/ her senior?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  Please note that in the Western world, while professional hierarchies do exist, they are much less explicit than in the East. The polite fiction here is to pretend everyone is equal in power and status. So to the extent we can, we try not to explicitly alter our behavior for speaking with our professional seniors and subordinates. One trap in particular you want to avoid is appearing ingratiating or unctuous to your bosses (esp. in front of other employees).

Comment: To paraphrase @DanBron, you don't want to come off as a kiss-ass. If your boss likes that sort of thing, he's a crummy boss. But none of  your coworkers will like it at all. And in another sense it can appear presumptuous; many bosses might think "Who are you to pass judgment on what I do?"

Comment: The thing about *appreciate* is that it's been overused to the extent of being meaningless at best, and dishonest at worst. I don't even remember the last time I heard anyone use "appreciate" and wasn't able to replace it with "don't give a shit" without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because *appreciate* varies significantly depending on the object of appreciation.

"I appreciate your help" or "I appreciate your feedback" often conveys the speaker's gratitude or thankfulness (see [definition 1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appreciate) below from dictionary.com.)

[image: appreciate]

---

"I appreciate your work" comes across as awkward, if not totally out of place, when uttered by a junior employee to a senior or a supervisor.

A supervisor or senior worker would say, "I appreciate your work" only under special circumstances, for instance, if the junior went above and beyond the "call of duty" in fulfilling a task or request of the supervisor.  It is more likely to occur if the supervisor or the institution were not going to make use of the junior employee's work. E.g. "I appreciate your work, but we had to submit the proposal before we received your input."

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on tone, of course--theoretically you could get away with saying "I appreciate your work" to a boss that you admire--but the much safer and more common thing to say would be "I admire your work". That's not kiss-ass, but it doesn't presume that you're in a position to be judging your boss's work.

You can (and should) "appreciate" your boss's or teacher's *help*, but I personally wouldn't say it in regards to their work.

It also depends on your relative ages, your relative time at the job, that sort of thing, so I think it's less a question of English language and usage and more a question of social appropriateness.